# The procedure named apex_admin could not be accessed

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle12c, apex, ord

Database : 12.2

apex : 22.2

ords : 22.3

after installation execute

http://localhost:8080/ords/apex_admin

appear a page :
Error 404 Not Found
The procedure named apex_admin could not be accessed, it may not be declared, or the user executing this request may not have been granted execute privilege on the procedure, or a function specified by security.requestValidationFunction configuration property has prevented access. Check the spelling of the procedure, check that the execute privilege has been granted to the caller and check the configured security.requestValidationFunction function. If using the PL/SQL Gateway Procedure Allow List, check that the procedure has been allowed via ords_admin.add_plsql_gateway_procedure.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PezZa.png)

I reinstalled the apex and ords also but got the same issue again. I can provide anydesk

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the file :
defaults.xml
and delete the lines:

```
<entry key="security.requestValidationFunction">wwv_flow_epg_include_modules.authorize</entry>
<entry key="security.validationFunctionType">plsql</entry>
```